# Does a matrix A and its reduced row echelon form R have the same nullspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I was thinking in terms of this. Consider the general solution to $Ax = 0$, represented in terms of free variables. Setting all but one of the free variables to 0, we get a vector in the nullspace of A. The vectors obtained this way are linearly independent and span the entire nullspace.

But how do I go about proving that both A and R have the same nullspace? I know that they do, but I was confused about how I should go about showing the same.

Answer (score 1):

The matrices $A$ and $R$ are linked by $R=EA$, where $E$ is invertible. Now checking they have the same null space is easy.